# Show and hide part of text in a table

Tags: javascript

Please Help

Show and hide part of text in a table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4Ize.gif)

Thank you

Comment: What did you try? Please post the code.

Comment: This looks like an assignment. Please post your try, at least.

Comment: Please add any code directly into the question. We cannot copy or execute code from an image and some users cannot even see images. Also, please see [**How do I ask a good question**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html dir="rtl">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

  <div align="center">
    (<span lang="ar-sa">0,5</span><span lang="en-us">)</span>substring
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table border="1" style="border-collapse: collapse" width="221" bordercolorlight="#808080" bordercolordark="#808080">
      <tr>
        <td><span lang="en">Hello all</span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><span lang="en">how are you</span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p align="center"><input type="button" value="    Hide    " name="B4"><span lang="en-us">&nbsp;&nbsp;
</span><input type="button" value="    show    " name="B3"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can show the full text on mouse hover and hide otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can show the full text on mouse hover and hide otherwise.

```
 <div>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td onmouseover="document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML='Text to Show'" onmouseout="document.getElementById('textbox').innerHTML='Truncated Text'">
            <div id="textbox">Truncated Text</div></td>
        </tr>  
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Deepa   Thank you for the same example